# showing exception while comparing string with null

Tags: java, android

My application showing null pointer exception while I am comparing a String variable is null or not

my error stack trace is as below

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appovative.poi/com.appovative.places.SinglePlaceDetails}:       java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.appovative.places.SinglePlaceDetails.onCreate(SinglePlaceDetails.java:73)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

my code in onCreate() method

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.single_place_map);



    Intent intent = getIntent();
    PlaceLocation placeLoc = (PlaceLocation) intent
            .getSerializableExtra("Place");

    double lat = placeLoc.getLat();
    double lng = placeLoc.getLng();
    title = placeLoc.getTitle();
    vicinity = placeLoc.getVic();

    if(title.toString().length() != 0 && vicinity.toString().length()!= 0)
    {
        sbMsg.append(title.toString()).append("\n").append(vicinity.toString());
    }
    else if(!title.equalsIgnoreCase("null") && vicinity.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
        sbMsg.append(title);
    }
}
```

I am getting null pointer exception in if(condition).

Comment: You're really not doing what you think you are doing.

Comment: I'd suggest overriding toString() method.

Comment: what is line 73 `SinglePlaceDetails.java`

Comment: @Raghunandan if(title.toString() != null && vicinity.toString() != null)

Comment: @Kunu can you post what `title` and `vincinty` is and where is it declared and initialized

Comment: @Raghunandan Please check my updated code sample

Comment: @Kunu looks like title and vincinty is null. Is  `PlaceLocation` a class implementing parcelable?? Also read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Comment: @Raghunandan My PlaceLocation class implementing Serilizable

Comment: @Kunu have a look at this blog http://androidhub.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/android-intents-for-passing-data-between-activities-part-3/ and the link in my previous comment. title and vincinty is null for some reason

Comment: This question is a complete mess.  It is nothing like the code in the original question, to which most of the comments and answers refer.  I have no idea if the stack trace you have shown relates to this code or some earlier version.  Please delete this question and start a new one with the stack trace and the exact code causing it.  I'm voting to close this one.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid using toString(), just do the null check

```
if(title != null && vicinity != null)
{
    tv.setText(title+ "\n"+vicinity);
}
```

Also make sure "tv" is assigned.

Comment: already tried , but it's also showing same exception

Comment: @Kunu: Well why haven't you told us what the exception is? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: @Amila i don't think it is related to swing. Its tagged android

Comment: @Kunu: Yup, you now haven't told us what line 73 of SinglePlaceDetails.java is...

Comment: @Raghunandan yeah, I read the stacktrace later.

Comment: @Kunu Post your code in onCreate()

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(title != null && vicinity != null)
    {
        if (tv != null) {
            tv.setText(title+ "\n"+vicinity);
        }
    }
```

You have to ensure that tv variable is not null. It may cause NullPointer Exception because it you have to set text to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use string!=null not string.equalsIgnoreCase

Answer (score 0):

Cause you can't use methods on null, first you should check that object isn't null.

For example:

```
if(title != null && vicinity != null && tv != null)
{
  tv.setText(title+ "\n"+vicinity);
}
```